# change data in Vuejs for all

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, vue.js

i have problem with this after ajax totalUserPosts return me Zero , i don't want this !

```
new Vue({
el: "#app",
data: {
  totalUserPosts:0,
},
methods:{
  getPostsAjax () {
    $.ajax({
      url:url,
      type: 'get',
      cache: false,
      dataType: "json",
      data:{
        limit: this.limit,
        id: this.vue_profile_id
      }
   }).done((data) => {
     this.userPosts = data.posts;
     this.totalUserPosts = data.total
   }.bind(this))
 },
 getUserPosts () {
   this.getPostsAjax()
   $(window).scroll(() => {
     if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 150) {
       console.log(this.totalUserPosts)
     }
   })
 }
})
```

i want change totalUserPosts after done ajax request help me please

Comment: can you put the console.log(this.totalUserPosts); inside the done function after it was assigned and tell us what the output is?

Comment: this return value of totalUserPosts = 11

Comment: this is not return Zero

Comment: have you tried declaring the `$(window).scroll` function inside the done function?

Comment: There are a couple of problems: 1) `getPostsAjax()` is an async method, so the code in `scroll()` after it will already be run before the Ajax call finished. My advice: use Promises or implement a callback so you can do `getPostsAjax(cbFunctionHere)`

2) Inside the callback to `.scroll()`, `this` will not point to the vue instance. you should use a normal function and bind it properly.

Comment: Well, based on what you've provided, which is all we have to go on, you don't have a url variable declared in your `url: url` key of your ajax call. If you have one defined above in the closure, please post complete data so we can better help you otherwise this is possibly your problem and you can confirm it by passing an error handler to the `error: errorHandlerFn` key in the ajax call

Answer (score 1):

You're calling scroll before the ajax function returns.  You should include the scroll functionality in the callback function of the ajax request, maybe like this:

```
    new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
      totalUserPosts:0,
    },
    methods:{
      getPostsAjax () {
        $.ajax({
          url:url,
          type: 'get',
          cache: false,
          dataType: "json",
          data:{
            limit: this.limit,
            id: this.vue_profile_id
          }
         }).done(this.getUserPosts)
        },
         getUserPosts (data) {
           this.userPosts = data.posts
           this.totalUserPosts = data.total
           $(window).scroll(() => {
           if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 150) {
             console.log(this.totalUserPosts)
           }
          })
         }
        },
        ready () {
         this.getPostsAjax();
        }
    })
```

Comment: no :( this return undefined for me :( another solution do u have ??

Comment: what exactly is undefined? cause this is what I was aiming at with my comment above. EDIT: problem with this solution is that "this" has another context because we are in the scroll event context. @Jeff: can you adjust your solution to use a variable instead of this?

Comment: The es16 arrow functions keep the scope in which they are written @TehSphinX